# Comma operator in Typescript

Tags: typescript

From MDN:

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

So to try this out I transformed this arrow function

```
const pushToArray = (a: FormArray, f: FormGroup) => {
   a.push(f)
   return a
}
```

to

```
const pushToArray = (a: FormArray, f: FormGroup) => { a.push(f), a }
```

However it doesn't seem to work, as

> TS2345 - Argument of type (a: FormArray, f: FormGroup) => void is not applicable ...

Why does that function return `void` now?
Maybe I misunderstood the **evaluates each of its operands** part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the curly braces you are declaring a method body. Since you have no `return` statement there, the type is inferred as `void`; hence your error.

Use parentheses instead:

```
const pushToArray = (a: FormArray, f: FormGroup) => (a.push(f), a)
```